# NodeJs Container Build fail in Xmcloud Foundation head

Tags: xm-cloud

Step 6/12 : RUN curl.exe -sS -L -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODEJS_VERSION%/node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-win-x64.zip ---> Running in db1248553e5c

Has anyone faced this issues?

[image]

Comment: Your containers can't see the internet. Follow the solutions on the other question.